# Spring MVC Return ResponseEntity<T> vs ResponseEntity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I use spring mvc and I dont understand difference between using ResponseEntity or ResponseEntity directly

Which one is better?And is there any difference between them

```
 public ResponseEntity<Person> get() {....

or

public ResponseEntity get(){.....
```

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly specifying the type of body you say of which type the response entity body is. If you don't specify any, then the resultig entity is not supposed to have any body - the `getBody()` method returns null.